# Flux - How does store should notify error?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Let's say component invoked an action and store tries to perform some operation but it couldn't, so store is trying to report the error back to view so user can be aware.

I can think of two options to handle this.

1. Have store emit an `error` event and then view components can listen to this event like they listen to `change` events and show the error to the user.
2. Store can add the error to the `state` object and fire a `change` event, then the the view components can check the error on the state objects and display error message accordingly.

Or is there any elegant way of handling this ?

Comment: You could also have the store dispatching an action going to a ErrorStore, that all the views listen to?

Comment: @JeremyD Hi, What would be the advantage of this approach over firing an 'error' event from store and having the components listen to it ?

Comment: Because you would have to duplicate a lot of code to do the same thing. Whereas with another store, it is a single source of truth to handle the error logic?

Comment: If you're using something like React my personal opinion is that the better option is to put the errors in the store's state. That way the component/view becomes more declarative ("render any errors in the state like this"). Firing events from the store adds another data flow, and that adds complexity even if it's in the same "direction" as the other store data. Having a dedicated error store probably means you'll have to put some kind of error type or metadata that each component would always have to check against to do something useful about the particular error.

Comment: Hi Hannes Johansson, thank you for the comment but when do you recommend to clear the error that we inserted in the state ? When ever the view fires the next action we clear the previously inserted error ?

Answer (score 1):

Store normal and error informations in the store state is a better way to do that. In your scenario, you may need to show a error dialog or something else in order to tell user something is broken. That is, you have to rerender your components according to different states, so just put the error information in your store state and emit a `change` event.

Put everything which makes components change in the store state. That allows everyone to know your data flow easily and quickly.